# Saving content from textarea to a div

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

How can I use **textarea** to save a note on the **todo** **div** by creating a **div** inside it? Do I have to save it in a database?

Below is the code for the **Sticky Note** Page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <h1 id="headline">Sticky note </h1>
    <div class="container-nav">
      <textarea id="submit-content"></textarea>
      <input type="button" onclick="addNote()" name="Post" class="submit-note" value="Post note">
    </div>

  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="column column-one" id="column-one">
        <h2>To do</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="column column-two" id="column-two">
        <h2>Ongoing</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="column column-three" id="column-three">
        <h2>Done</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you're asking more than one question here. Please be specific and focus on one issue at a time.

Comment: You can't create elements nested inside of `textarea` - only text.

Comment: You use a separate Element, other than the `<textarea>` to output your contents. If using `.innerHTML` make sure you use the proper special character escaping.

Comment: Okey, so to be more specific. When i for example write "hello world" inside the text-area, i want it to appear on the "to-do" column. Do i have to create a database to be able store what i write inside the textarea to the "to-do" column?

Comment: A database isn't necessary. If you want it to persist after closing/refreshing/etc, you would need to store it somewhere (be it a database, cookies, local storage, or just an external .txt file). But just displaying the textarea contents in a div is pretty simple javascript.

Comment: @BrandonLyons YES! This is basicly what i am wondering about. So my next question. How can i create a div within the div from the textarea?

Answer (score 0):

First, get the contents of the textarea. Then, append a new div to the `.innerHTML` of the container of wherever you want your div. Code is as follows

```
var content = document.getElementById("submit-content").value;
document.getElementById("whichever-container-you-want-it-in").innerHTML += "<div>" + content + "</div>;
```

Put this in your `addNote()` function, changing the attributes (id/class/etc) as needed.

Comment: Ideally one wouldn't bind an event handler in the HTML.

Comment: I’m assuming you’d add a listener in the JS - why is that better?

Comment: Yes, you'd add it to the JS. Separation of concerns, ease of maintenance (imagine having `addNote()` on 50 elements spread across 10 pages and had to change it in some way, yuck), bind multiple handlers per event (or at least, more easily), etc.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Similar benefits to using external style sheets over in-line. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since the level of persistence has not been clearly defined this solution only copies a note from the `<textarea>` to the *To Do* column. It is not stored anywhere (i.e. database, cookie, localStorage ).

If I need to create elements via JS I typically do it with [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement). To add this newly created element to the DOM you will need a reference to the element it will be added to, I prefer [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). Then use the [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) method to add the new DIV as the last element to the parent element.

```js
var note = document.querySelector( '#submit-content' );
var post = document.querySelector( '.submit-note' );
var toDo = document.querySelector( '#column-one' );

/**
 * Add note from textarea to a column.
 *
 * @param {DOMNode} column The column to add a note to.
 * @param {String}  note   The note/text from the textarea.
 */
function addNote( column, note ) {

  var div = document.createElement( 'div' );
  
  div.textContent = note;
  column.appendChild( div );
  
}

post.addEventListener( 'click', function ( e ) {
  addNote( toDo, note.value );
  note.value = '';
} );
```

```html
<h1 id="headline">Sticky note </h1>
<div class="container-nav">
  <textarea id="submit-content"></textarea>
  <input type="button" name="Post" class="submit-note" value="Post note">
</div>

<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="column column-one" id="column-one">
      <h2>To do</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="column column-two" id="column-two">
      <h2>Ongoing</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="column column-three" id="column-three">
      <h2>Done</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

This example also shows how to bind an event handler via JS instead of the HTML, which is the preferred approach.